# Javascript check the form current data is equal to its original data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

when I use form.reset() in javascript. The function will reset the form to its original state. for example:

```
<form id="myForm">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname" value="??"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br><br>
  <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Reset form">
</form>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
    form.reset();
}
</script>
```

when I running this code the first input field will be reset to "??" (which is the original value). How does javascript get this value? Can I access it?

I am building an website which need to check if user has changed any value of the form. If nothing changes I want to stop user from submitting the form. that's why I am asking is there any way I can have a general method to check if the current value of some field is equal to its original value.

Comment: I just find I can use element.defaultValue to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value of an input element is set by entering value="default value" in the element itself, as you have done in your first one.  Resetting a form returns the input elements to their default values.

To access an element's default value, you would access the defaultValue property.

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('firstName').defaultValue;
```

jQuery (since you tagged jQuery in your question):

```
$('#firstName')[0].defaultValue;
```

When the form is submitted, you can easily check the current form value against the default form value.

Here is an example that takes advantage of jQuery to do this:

**HTML**

```
<form id="myForm">
    <label for="firstName">First name:</label>
    <input id="firstName" type="text" name="fname" value="defaultval1" />
    <br />
    <label for="lastName">Last name:</label>
    <input id="lastName" type="text" name="lname" value="defaultval2" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <input id="btnSubmit" type="button" value="Submit" />
    <input id="btnReset" type="button" value="Reset" />
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function hasAnythingChanged() {
    var hasChanged = false;
    $('#myForm :input[type=text]').each(function () {
        if (this.defaultValue != this.value) {
            hasChanged = true;
        }
    });
    return hasChanged;
}

$(function () {
    $('#btnReset').on('click', function () {
        var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
        form.reset();
    });

    $('#btnSubmit').on('click', function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (hasAnythingChanged()) {
            alert('Submitting at least one changed value!');
            // Do your submit action here
        } else {
            alert('Please change at least one value.')
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/BenjaminRay/jLvh98br/